# select multiple DataFrame from Pandas dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary 'dict' of Pandas DataFrames named 'df1', 'df2', 'df3', etc.
I now want to decimate the dictionary by selecting only a few data frames, e.g. df1 and df2

if I try to pass a list

```
dict1 = dict1[['df1', 'df3']]
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Pandas and is more a Python issue.

Try:

```
dict_new = {k: dict1[k] for k in ['df1', 'df3']}
```